# Godot3 change color of meshInstance

Tags: godot

How can I change mesh color in Godot3 properly?

```
extends MeshInstance

# class member variables go here, for example:
# var a = 2
# var b = "textvar"
var i=0
export(Color) var new_color = Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
func _ready():
    var n = self
    var mat=n.get_mesh().surface_get_material(0)
    var mat2 = SpatialMaterial.new()
    mat2.albedo_color = Color(0.8, 0.0, 0.0)
    self.get_mesh().surface_set_material(0,mat2)
    set_process(true)
    # Called every time the node is added to the scene.
    # Initialization here
func _process(delta):
    randomize()
    var mat2 = SpatialMaterial.new()
    mat2.albedo_color = Color8(255, 0, 0)
    var i = rand_range(0.0,100.0)
    if i>50.0:
        self.get_mesh().surface_set_material(0,mat2)
        i=0
    else:
        mat2.albedo_color = Color8(0, 0, 255)
        self.get_mesh().surface_set_material(0,mat2)
```

I tried this simple code to change mesh color in godot3 engine. The idea might help to change the steplight color of the car for example in some game.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. If you want something different than my solution, please add a more thorough description of your goals.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `material_override` property of the MeshInstance and the `albedo_color` property of the material (SpatialMaterial), setting the color to whatever you need:

The example below changes the color of the MeshInstance to a shade of orange:

```
func _ready():
    var newMaterial = SpatialMaterial.new() #Make a new Spatial Material
    newMaterial.albedo_color = Color(0.92, 0.69, 0.13, 1.0) #Set color of new material
    $"MeshInstance".material_override = newMaterial #Assign new material to material overrride
```

First, make a new SpatialMaterial and assign it a name. Then, set the color of that material and set that material as the override material for the MashInstance. Just replace "MeshIsntance" with the name of your MeshInstance. For example, if this line is included in the script attached to the MeshInstance itself:

```
func _ready():
    var newMaterial = SpatialMaterial.new()
    newMaterial.albedo_color = Color(0.92, 0.69, 0.13, 1.0)
    self.material_override = newMaterial
```

If you want to undo the override:

```
self.material_override = null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the material color in this way:

```
extends MeshInstance

export(Color) var new_color = Color(1, 1, 1, 1)

func _ready():
    randomize()
    get_surface_material(0).albedo_color = new_color
    set_process(true)
```

You can also add a material override (SpatialMaterial) in the inspector under "GeometryInstance" and set its `albedo` property to the desired color in your script.

```
material_override.albedo_color = new_color
```